# ios facebook sdk permissions differ for native and web/fast app switch - how to resolve?

Tags: ios, facebook

I find that when I try to openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions, the permission public_profile is required for web/fast app switch login.

However, that permission doens't work with native login (i.e. using the account set in system preferences).

I have verified with the latest SDK on both iOS 7 and 8 the following:
openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions will work with "basic_info" for native login; but will fail with "public_profile"
openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions will work with "public_profile" but fail with "basic_info" for web, and fast app switching.

So how are we meant to resolve this?